# Error handling in `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`

Tags: python, exception, python-datamodel

**Note** this questions is answered in the comments

I've noticed some behaviour with exception handling in `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` that I can't find mentioned in the docs, or other posts on here.

Consider this class `A`. If an instance of `A` has an attribute that is `None`, accessing that attribute raises an `AttributeError`.

```
class A:
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if value is None:
            raise AttributeError('in __getattribute__')

        return value

    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a

A(1).a  # 1
A().a  # raises AttributeError('in __getattribute__')
```

Now, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) on `__getattribute__` say

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.

From this, I would have guessed that any `AttributeError` raised in `__getattribute__` would always be caught and the process deferred to `__getattr__`, such that `AttributeError('in __getattribute__')` would never be seen by the caller.

To my surprise, not only is the error seen, but the `AttributeError` raised on `A().a` is the one in `__getattribute__`, as though `__getattr__` had never been called. That is *unless* `__getattr__` raises its own

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    raise AttributeError('in __getattr__')
```

in which case we see `AttributeError('in __getattr__')` raised instead.

What are the rules here? And do they apply if instead of `AttributeError('in __getattribute__')` i'd raised some subclass `Oops` of `AttributeError` in `__getattribute__`?

Comment: `If the class also defines __getattr__()` - your class doesn't define `__getattr__`

Comment: @snakecharmerb curious, what happens to the `__getattr__` inherited from `object`?

Comment: weird - there isn't a `__getattr__` on `object` (try `object.__getattr__`). what do the docs mean by `object.__getattr__` then?

Comment: ah, "The following methods **can be** defined to customize the meaning of attribute access (use of, assignment to, or deletion of x.name) for class instances."

Comment: So what is the problem here? I don't see any.

Comment: @CristiFati i think the docs aren't clear enough that `__getattr__` isn't inherited from `object`. I'll leave this here while I raise a ticket with python docs

Comment: As a matter of fact, they are: "*If the class also **defines** ...*" (**defines** not **inherits**). They don't specify that *object* would define it (`print(dir(object))`), that 's you own assumption.

Comment: you're right, it does say that, and i did assume it, but i would have found it helpful when reading it for that to be clearer e.g. to highlight 'defines' like you have

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the comments.

[[Python 3.Docs]: Data model - object.**__getattribute__**(*self, name*)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) (**emphasis** is mine) states:

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. **If the class also defines [__getattr__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)**, the latter will not be called unless [__getattribute__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) either calls it explicitly or raises an [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError). This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) exception. In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation should always call the base class method with the same name to access any attributes it needs, for example, `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`.

The confusion was because of the assumption that *__getattr__* is inherited from *object* (which is false):

> ```py
> >>> dir(object)
> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
> >>>
> >>> object.__getattribute__
> <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
> >>> object.__getattr__
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
> ```

Although I can understand why it might be confusing for some people, from what I am concerned (after going through the *doc* multiple times), it's pretty clear: 
**If *__getattr__* was inherited from *object*, then the (quoted) text "*If the class also defines __getattr__()*" would make no sense**.